# get multiple twitter feed with jquery

Tags: jquery, json, twitter

i am trying to get twitter feed using jQuery json i can get the below code to work, if i don't use a for loop.
can anyone guide me how can i get it work to get multiple tweets?
while i try to use another url : https://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/maxlibin.json?callback=twitterCallback2&count=3
still don't work

```
jQuery.getJSON("https://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/maxlibin.json?callback=?", function(data) {
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        jQuery("#main .left").html(data[0].text);
    });​
```

Answer (score 2):

```
jQuery.getJSON("https://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/maxlibin.json?callback=?", function(data) {
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        jQuery("#main .left").append(data[i].text);
    };
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QfSbs/

With a little more work, you can stick each one in a separate paragraph and automatically link the URLs:

```
jQuery.getJSON("https://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/maxlibin.json?callback=?", function(data) {
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        jQuery("#main .left").append($('<p>').html(data[i].text.replace(/(http:\/\/[^\s]+)\b/g, '<a href="$1">$1</a>')));
    };
});
​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QfSbs/1/

Answer (score 0):

Each time you use `html(...)` You override anything inside the element.

Extract all the data, then append it to the element:

```
var output = "";
for (i=0; i<4; i++){
    output += data[i].text;
}
jQuery("#main .left").html(output);
```

Note that you didn't use the loop index, you just used `0` for all the iterations: `...html(data[0].text);`

Comment: @godoron however this does not phase a link.

Comment: @LiBin. **I can't debug the code for you.** If you have extra information about the errors you're getting, update me.